# How to output info to a listbox?

Tags: vba, ms-access

This code gives me

> "data member not found"

when trying to output my info to a listbox.

```vb
    Dim ClassYoga(5) As Integer
    Dim NumOfAttend As Integer
    Dim index As Integer

    'initialize array
    index = 0
    Do Until index > 4
        ClassYoga(index) = 0
        index = index + 1
    Loop

    'first input from user

    NumOfAttend = InputBox("How many people will be attending class? (555 to quit")
    
    Do Until NumOfAttend = 555
        ClassYoga(NumOfAttend - 1) = ClassYoga(NumOfAttend - 1) + 1
        
        NumOfAttend = InputBox("How many people will be attending class? (555 to quit")
    Loop
    
    'display

    index = 0
    
    lstYoga.RowSource = vbNullString
    
    Do Until index > 4
        lstYoga.AddItem ((index + 1) & "Attendants :" * ClassYoga(index))
    Loop
```

It returns errors on the `.rowsource` and `.additem` functions.

How can I output my results?

Answer (score 0):

In the last do-loop you do not increment index,

Comment: Corrected that, but I still get the compile error of 'method or data member not found' and it points at lstyoga.rowsource and .additem as the culprits for the errors.

Comment: try this lstYoga.RowSourceType = "Value List"

Comment: you can also change the RowSourceType from the editor, i've tested your code and it works after fixing the increment.

Comment: @HansUp There's an explicitly named listbox, but explicit option isn't in

Comment: @JasonK. Did you change anything else other than the increment?

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` and run Debug->Compile from the VB editor's main menu.  If `lstYoga.RowSource` is in a standard module, Access will highlight `lstYoga` and complain *"Variable not defined"* because it doesn't know that is a listbox.  In that case, copy your code to the form's module and test it there.

Comment: @HansUp I’ll try that when I get out of class

Comment: 9 hours later It's still broken. I've completely re-wrote it and it's still coming up with the same error on the same lines and it won't display output. I have no idea.

Comment: @HansUp Alright, there's something going on here with my access and it's current config. I just went back to some old homework databases and they work perfectly. If i rebuild them on a new database, I'm getting the same return, that the error is on the lst.additems and .rowsources. Any Ideas? My code works perfectly on an old database i've saved, just tried it.

Comment: If the code works perfectly in that old database, why not just use that one and call this "problem solved"?

Comment: @HansUp I like your thinking, just wish I knew why it won't work in a NEW database. lol. Oh well, Problem solved.

Comment: @JasonK. OP can't upvote until they have at least 15 reputation.